# No way to resolve conflict between versions

Tags: c#

I'm totally new in C#. I got a warning during the build:

```
MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly.
```

Now I used AmSpy to find which assemby. The output was:

```
No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and 
"mscorlib, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
```

Now I my question? How or where do I have to change the version? (One is 2.0.0.0 and the other is 4.0.0.0

Thanks

Comment: Start with trying an "assembly binding redirect".  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)

Comment: Right-click the project in the Solution explorer, and choose properties.  It should be the 2nd drop-down on the left.

Comment: @BradleyUffner in visual studio 2017?